I got login error while using instabot it happens at the second time only, how to solve it?
I tried to login using instabot
I used tihs:
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username=username, password=passwd)

It logged in correctly at the first time, but when I tried to do it again that error happend:


2024-06-19 16:14:32,464 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>

    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start

    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)

  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/instabot/bot/bot.py", line 443, in login

    if self.api.login(**args) is False:

       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/instabot/api/api.py", line 240, in login

    self.load_uuid_and_cookie(load_cookie=use_cookie, load_uuid=use_uuid)

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/instabot/api/api.py", line 199, in load_uuid_and_cookie

    return load_uuid_and_cookie(self, load_uuid=load_uuid, load_cookie=load_cookie)

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.11/site-packages/instabot/api/api_login.py", line 352, in load_uuid_and_cookie

    cookie_username = self.cookie_dict["ds_user"]

                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^

KeyError: 'ds_user'





I tried to delete cookie file but if I did it a lot and login every time I use the script I think it will raise Instagram's suspicions.
